# Display welcome message in new tmux session

Tags: bash, tmux

In a bash script, a new tmux session is started, several processes are launched in separate panes, then the session is attached to the current terminal. I would like to display a short message that gives a few helpful hints how to navigate panes, exit the session etc.

I tried to just echo, but that is not executed inside the session. Is there a good approach how to do this?

Edit: my use case is to have everything contained in a repository. I want to avoid adding config to dotfiles or anything in the user's home dir.

Comment: You might want to use the `display-message` command.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you could print your message perhaps:

- Make tmux enter copy mode with some output, for example: `tmux new \; run 'echo hello'`
- Run a script in a new window that prints the output: `tmux neww 'echo hello; sleep 5'`
- Make one of your panes (if your tmux is new enough) open a popup: `tmux new 'tmux popup -KER "echo hello; sleep 5"; exec $SHELL"`

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if there are tmux specific environment variables set in your .bashrc and print a message if they exist

eg. in your .bashrc

```
if [ ! -z "$TMUX" ]; then
    echo "Your message"
fi
```

Comment: Yes, that would work, but not for my use case. I'll edit the question for clarity, thank you :)

Comment: See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/492266/run-or-send-a-command-to-a-tmux-pane-in-a-running-tmux-session)